# selection multiple radio button by java script using button id

Tags: javascript, php

all the radio button names are to be same. so i want to call using their using id. is it valid to call them by id? if it is please help me about it.

```
function selectAll( prefix, set ) {
        var form = document.forms[0], //Get the appropriate form
            i = 0,
            radio;
        while( radio = form[prefix + ++i] ) //Loop through all named radio# elements
            for( var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++ ) //Loop through each set of named radio buttons
                if( radio[j].value == (set ? "yes" : "no") ) //Selector based on value of set
                    radio[j].checked = true; //Check that radio button!






        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo"<tr><td>{$row['roll']}</td>
                    </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>
                    <td><input id='file' type='radio' name='radio[$i]' value='Yes'>YES</td>
                          </td><td></td><td></td><td>
                          <td><input type='radio' name='radio[$i]' value='No'>NO</td></tr>";
                          $i++;
                }
```

Comment: radio buttons, by design, can only be selected one per name. Maybe you want checkboxes?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use checkboxes? Only one radio button per radio group can be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this: give each "Yes" radio button unique id, loop through them and set checked property to true:

```
`function selectAll()
 {
  for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  {
   var id = "file" + i;
   var element = document.getElementById(id);
   element.checked = true;
  }
 }`
```

And your php code:

```
`echo "<tr><td>$row</td>
       </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>
       <td><input type='radio' name='radio$i' id='file$i' value='Yes'>YES</td>
       </td><td></td><td></td><td>
       <td><input type='radio' name='radio$i' value='No'>NO</td>`</tr>";`
```

Of course as others suggested the best/quicekst is to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If your Main focus is to select all the radio button you can give a class name for the radio button and make it get checked on button click event.

Answer (score 0):

we will sugesst to use jquery instead of javascript.
You just have to include one jquery library and can jquery code at any place of your javascript code.
As jquery is advanced form of javascript and is easy to use. so all the task will better perform in jquery by selecting simply radio button class and than checked them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="radioList">    
    <input type="radio" class="check" />
    <input type="radio" class="check" />
    <input type="radio" class="check" />
    <input type="radio" class="check" />
    <input type="radio" class="check" />
</div>
```

below jquery wll help

```
  $('.check').prop("checked", true)
```

or

```
 $('#radioList input:radio').prop("checked", true)
```